# django-rest-auth: how to get user info after successful authentication?

Tags: django-rest-auth

The `django-rest-auth` returns a token after successful authentication using `rest_auth.serializers.TokenSerializer`. How can I override this serializer or add my own so that I can get the user info like username, instead of token key after successful authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by defining a custom serializer.

```python
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_auth.models import TokenModel

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email')

class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = TokenModel
        fields = ('key', 'user')
```

You can also use the `depth` option to easily generate nested representations, but in that case, you will receive the `password` field as well, which is not expected and intended.